# Rand al'Thor's head found rolling?

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. American school's public relations incorporated by UK school (9)
>   6. Part of the face with new colour (5)
>   9. English university city where 23 down is located (9)
>   10. Top Caribbean resort's opening inside of UK's westernmost island (5)
>   11. Ask her out, Christian (6)
>   13. Making old university in country's capital (8)
>   15. "Sit up!" – frequent line of Monty Python presenter (3)
>   16. Forbidden dance missing a bit of authentic character (6)
>   20. Teller's partner is an Oscar winner (4)
>   21. School held in delayed retreat (4)
>   22. He's in character for a soulmate (3,3)
>   25. Private investigator not quiet at the back (3)
>   27. People who choose or select cast (8)
>   28. The case of crazy alien robot (6)
>   31. Listen, look: A source of protein (5)
>   33. William using lying gems in a funny way (9)
>   35. Some triple-X ecstasy for directors (5)
>   36. Vader takes man out to college (9)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Animal groups acknowledging leaders in public school, initially (5)
>   2. Ideology is the leader of masses (3)
>   3. Fallen rock covering up university (7)
>   4. Orderly taxi delivery cases (4)
>   5. New excellent video: "Moving Like a Mole" (7)
>   6. Reinforcements retreat (4,2)
>   7. Blade Runner's last to follow central road (3)
>   8. Learner to learn tune, loosely? (6,3)
>   12. Relieve muscles by wild love (7)
>   14. Hybrid 18 down with hybrid foal (7)
>   15. Guy I leave confused describing several answers here (3,6)
>   17. A Connecticut legislation's decree (3)
>   18. Be heard, small insect (3)
>   19. Rand al'Thor's head found near 3 down's region, rolling (3)
>   23. 36 across's backer followed by a recreational vehicle on a road leading to school (7)
>   24. God with total following, heavenly at last, taking one to the afterlife (7)
>   26. Street rat's new beginnings (6)
>   29. Hosted by ugly, philanderous character (5)
>   30. Industrial area of Rolls-Royce outside of Utah's borders (4)
>   32. Cancel a cross-examination's start (3)
>   34. Antelope in rising numbers (3)

Comment: Nope, I'm fine thank you.

Comment: Any resemblance to any real or fictional heads is purely for clickbait purposes. No people or animals where harmed during the making of this puzzle.

Comment: The Rand clue is very clever. Very much liked the theme of this one too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is the completed crossword

> [image]

Clue explanations

> **Across**
>  1. P.R + Inc + Eton
>  6. Brow + N
>  9. double def
>  10. C(aribbean) + Of containing R(esort) + U(K)
>  11. (Ask her)*
>  13. Change O to U in Colombia
>  15. (Sit)*  [reference for the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recurring_Monty_Python%27s_Flying_Circus_characters#%22It's%22_man)
>  16. Lambada missing "a", character is the def.
>  20. Double def
>  21. (d)elay(ed) <
>  22. HE in TONE
>  25. SHAFT - SH, "at the back" is the def.
>  27. (Or select)*
>  28. C(raz)y + Borg
>  31. Sounds like Glare
>  33. (Willi)am using ly(ing)
>  35. (tripl)e-X ecs(tasy)
>  36. Darth containing M out
>  **Down**
>  1. Ack inside P(ublic) S(chool)
>  2. Is + M(asses)
>  3. (Fa)llen roc(k) <
>  4. T(ax)i + d(eliver)y
>  5. N + A + (video)*
>  6. Double def
>  7. (r)oa(d) + (runne)r
>  8. (learn tune)*
>  12. Abs + (love)*
>  14. Bee + (foal)*
>  15. (Guy I leave)*
>  17. A + Ct
>  18. Sounds like be
>  19. A(l'Thor) + (NY)*
>  23. (Dartmout)H + A + R.V + A + RD
>  24. EL (heavenl)Y + S(I)UM
>  26. St + (rats)*
>  29. (U)gly ph(ilanderous)
>  30. U(ta)h inside R.R.
>  32. A + X + E(xamination)
>  34. (Risin)g nu(mbers)